# How to specify source location in wix

Tags: wix, windows-installer

How do I make the sources specified in a heat generated file visible to the build?

I've got a project named `Foo` and a project named `FooSetup`. They have the same parent directory. To generate the list of files to install I ran in `FooSetup`:

```
heat dir "..\Foo\bin\Release" -cg "SomeGroupName" -ag -template:fragment -out heat.wxs
```

Now when I try to build the installer, I get:

```
The system cannot find the file 'SourceDir\Foo.dll'.
```

(that file does exist in the `Release` directory)

The path to `Foo\bin\Release` is specified in include paths in the `FooSetup` project properties.

What am I missing here - why is none of the listed files found?

Answer (score 1):

> ***WiX Learning Resources***: A couple of links to resources on WiX:
>
> - [Click-by-click WiX and Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130)
> - [Long list of WiX links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)

---

***WiX Preprocessor Variables***: What is SourceDir? [Rob Mensching (WiX creator) on SourceDir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145075/129130).

[As explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8590298/129130) you can change SourceDir to a [compiler variable](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/preprocessor.html):

***Heat.exe***: Something like this:

```
"%WIX%bin\heat.exe" dir . -sfrag -suid -ag -var MyReleasePath -out MySource.wxs
```

You will get something like this:

```
<!-- Extract -->

  <Component Id="MyFile.exe" Guid="*">
     <File Id="MyFile.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(MyReleasePath)\MyFile.exe" />
  </Component>

<!-- End of Extract -->
```

***WiX Sample***: Then you insert this into your source. Something like this:

```
<!-- START OF COMPILER VARIABLES: -->
<?define MyVersion = "1.0.0.0" ?>
<?define MyReleasePath = "C:\My Releases\Wix Testing\" ?>
<!-- END OF COMPILER VARIABLES: -->

<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">

  <Product Id="*" Name="WiX Testing" Language="1033" Version="$(var.MyVersion)"
           Manufacturer="WiX Testing" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">

    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

    <!-- Enable line below for GUI in MSI -->
    <!-- <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" /> -->
    
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />
    <Feature Id="Main" Title="Main Feature" Level="1" />

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WiX Testing">

         <!-- Essential part follows: -->

          <Component Feature="Main">
            <File Source="$(var.MyReleasePath)MyFile.exe"></File>
          </Component>

         <!-- End of Essential part -->

        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Product>

</Wix>
```

***Batch File Compile***: Visual Studio takes care of most of the build issues once you have defined the variables. If you want to compile "manually", here is a quick sample:

```
"%WIX%bin\candle.exe" MySource.wxs -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log
"%WIX%bin\light.exe" -out Test.msi MySource.wixobj -ext WixUIExtension >> Build.log
```

---

***Links:***

- [WiX sample for other issue at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54766353/129130)

Comment: I got it to kind of work with some changes. `-var MyReleasePath` had to be `-var var.MyReleasePath` to compile. Instead of copying the whole heat generated file, I used `-cg AppFiles -dr INSTALLFOLDER`, added `ComponentGroupRef` to the `Feature` and had to comment out the `<Directory Id="Release" Name="Release">` in the heat generated file.